# About norm of ideals in number fields

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$ be an extension of number fields, and denote the corresponding ring of integers by $O_K$ and $O_L$. Let $I=\frak{I}=\langle \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \rangle$ be a non-principal ideal of $O_L$. I am curious about what can we say about the relation between $\text{Norm}(\frak{I})$ and $\text{Norm}(\alpha_1)$, $\text{Norm}(\alpha_2)$?

If we are allowed to speak about the "$\gcd$ of elements", then I guess

$$\text{Norm}({I}) = \gcd \Bigg(\text{Norm}(\alpha_1), \text{Norm}(\alpha_2)\Bigg)$$.

> Under which conditions I can speak of $\gcd$ for elements of $\gcd \Bigg(\text{Norm}(\alpha_1), \text{Norm}(\alpha_2)\Bigg)$. If the above relation is true, how can I prove it?

---

My attempts:

Clearly $\text{Norm}(\alpha_i) \in \frak I$. Therefor any linear combination of $\text{Norm}(\alpha_i)$'s belongs to $\frak I$, especially their $\gcd$ (if we are allowed to speak about it). So if the context allows (I mean "gcd" and ...), then $\text{Norm}({I}) \mid \gcd \Bigg(\text{Norm}(\alpha_1), \text{Norm}(\alpha_2)\Bigg)$.

For $\gcd \Bigg(\text{Norm}(\alpha_1), \text{Norm}(\alpha_2)\Bigg) \mid \text{Norm}({I})$, I don't have any idea.

Comment: how about $K=\mathbb Q(i)$, $L=\mathbb Q$, and $(1)=(1+2i,1-2i)$?

Comment: @user8268 thank you for your example. [1] In general context, can we say that $\text{Norm}({I})$ divides $\gcd \Bigg(\text{Norm}(\alpha_1), \text{Norm}(\alpha_2), \cdots, \text{Norm}(\alpha_t)\Bigg)$? [2] In general context, let $I=\frak{I}=\langle \alpha_1, \alpha_2 \rangle$ be a non-principal ideal, do we have $\text{Norm}({I}) = \gcd \Bigg(\text{Norm}(\alpha_1), \text{Norm}(\alpha_2)\Bigg)$?

Comment: @user8268 I will apply some edits on my question.

Comment: in my example the norm of the ideal is $1$ and the norms of both of the generators are $5$. For your additional question: the norm of an ideal divides the norms of all its elements.

Comment: The norm is the order of the group $O_K/I$ and being a quotient of $O_K/(\alpha)$ we have $\# O_K/I \ | \ \#O_K/(\alpha)$